# I am using Python and Selenium in order to automate site testing and cant get selenium to submit a form

Tags: python, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used selenium to navigate the company site and fill out a specific form, but cannot get it to submit the form.

```
br = webdriver.Firefox()
```

---

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg place-order" value="Place Order" 
       ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid || submitted == true" disabled="disabled">
```

---

```
//*[@id="errorTop"]/div[5]/div/div[3]/form/div[4]/div[2]/input
```

Above is the form info as well as the xpath of the form, I have tried the following to capture and click the submit button:

#### First try

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.place-order').click()
```

#### Second try

```
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="errorTop"]/div[5]/div/div[3]/form/div[4]/div[2]/input').click()
```

Neither of which delivered the desired form submitting click.

Comment: Why find by css selector and not by class?

Comment: @user2717954, good suggestion, I tried that and it worked out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is definitely good but your submit button is disabled: `disabled="disabled"`, which is why you can't click on it.

Make sure it's not disabled before doing `.click()`.